# Do "nested" and "embedded" mean the same?

Tags: word-usage

1. When we have a loop and a second loop inside it, how do you refer to
   the outer loop and the inner loop?

   Which one would you call the "embedded" loop, and which one the
   "nested" loop?

   Which one would you call the "embedding" loop, and which one the
   "nesting" loop?

   Is it correct to say that the outer loop nests the inner loop, and
   the inner loop is embedded in the outer loop?
2. Another example from a book in database

   > A **nested** query is  a  query  that  has  another  query 
   >   **embedded**  within  it.
   >
   > The **embedded**  query  can   be a  **nested**  query  itself;  thus
   >   queries  that have  very deeply nested structures are possible.

   I guess the author means the outer query by the "nested" query, and
   the inner query the "embedded" query. However, I feel both the
   "nested" query and the "embedded" query should refer to the inner
   query wrt the outer query.

   why not call the outer query the "nesting" query, and the inner query both the "nested" query and the "embedded" query?

Thanks.

Comment: There are few technical terms programmers can really agree on. You'll find different definitions in every shop.

Comment: Outer loop, inner loop, nested loop, nested query, embedded object are all frequently used. But neither *embedding* nor *nesting* is a term-of-art that means 'that which embeds|nests something inside itself'.

Answer (score 6):

The main difference is that ***nested*** is much more likely to be used when one ***X*** is contained within *another, "higher-level" **X***. Whereas an ***embedded X*** simply means an ***X*** which is within *something* - not necessarily another ***X*** (and in fact *probably* not, since if it was, we'd probably have used *nested*).

Thus in programming contexts we often refer to ***nested*** loops/queries (within higher-level loops/queries). But a [gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) graphic image *within an email* (as opposed to an email attachment) is an ***embedded*** image.

I'm sure you'd be understood if you referred to the ***nesting*** loop/query, but ***outer*** is the standard term (or sometimes, ***containing***).

Answer (score 2):

**why not call the outer query the "nesting" query, and the inner query both the "nested" query and the "embedded" query?**

The reason why the outer loop (*mutatis mutandis*, outer query) is not called a *nesting* loop is that the verb *nest* is intransitive. It does not mean "to enclose in a nest" but "to be in a nest".

The reason why the container is not called the *embedding* object is because "embed" is a transitive verb that means "to put something in something else". The container does not put the object inside itself. Rather, some other thing puts the object in the container.

Answer (score 1):

As a AmE programmer, I use the words "nested" and "embedded" as you describe in #2:
"Nested functions contain embedded loops."

Using the "ed" is the correct adjective form instead of "nesting".
An example would be
"Please use the nested function getIt()" rather than saying "Use the nesting function getIt()".
Another example would be
"You will probably need to write a nested loop here to implement that algorithm."
Otherwise it sounds a bit odd, like a bird "nesting" on a tree branch.

There is also the connotation that the function is "complete", so, the function is "already" nested, not just sitting there "nesting".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesting_%28computing%29
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function